# Centralizar div sem width em um display: flex

Tags: css, css3

Tenho a seguinte **estrutura**:

```
<div id="peca" class="cinzaClaroBB">

    <section class="sessao peca">

        <div>

            <img src="folder.jpg">
            <img src="cartao.jpg">

        </div>

    </section>

</div>
```

`div#peca` e `section.peca` são `display: flex`.
a `div` que abriga as **imagens** não tem `width`.

Como **centralizar** essa `div` na `section`?

Eu tentei da forma abaixo e não funcionou!

```
/*PECA INICIO*/
body div#peca {
    background-color: #dae4ee;
    background: url(../../img/iconesHome/compras4.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
body div#peca > section.peca {
    width: 80%;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
body div#peca > section.peca > div img {
    height: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*PECA FIM*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas ela já está centralizada amigo. Se uma `div` não tem largura definida ela vai ter 100% da largura do pai. Então se o pai é o `body` um `div` dentro do `body` fica com 100% da largura do `body`

No seu caso vc tem uma `div` sem `width` definido dentro de uma `section` que tem largura de 80%, então essa `div` dentro da `section` fica com 100% da largura do `section`.

Aqui eu coloquei apenas uma borda para vc poder perceber os limites dos elementos. Veja que a `div` entra "centraliza" na `section`. Pois a `div` tem 100% da largura da `section` como explique acima.

**Resumindo:** Se uma `div` tem 100% da largura da `section` e está dentro da `section`, ela automaticamente já fica centralizada, pois ela ocupa 100% do espaço da section.

O elemento de borda vermelha é a `section`, e borda petra e a `div` sem largura definida, ou seja 100% da largura do pai, pois a `div` é um elemento do tipo `block` e ocupa 100% da largura do *container*, a não ser que vc coloque uma largura definida nela.

```css
/*PECA INICIO*/
body div#peca {
    background-color: #dae4ee;
    background: url(../../img/iconesHome/compras4.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
body div#peca > section.peca {
    width: 80%;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    border: 4px solid #f00;
}
body div#peca > section.peca > div img {
    height: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

section.peca > div  {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
}
/*PECA FIM*/
```

```html
<div id="peca" class="cinzaClaroBB">

  <section class="sessao peca">

      <div>

          <img src="folder.jpg">
          <img src="cartao.jpg">

      </div>

  </section>

</div>
```